# Distinguish Transitive/Intransitive verbs in dictionary

Tags: grammar

I am having a hard time finding this information in dictionaries.
I mainly use this one: https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/mainAction

Information that doesn't seem to appear when I look up verbs is whether or not the verb is a transitive one or not.

In comparison with English, when I look up verbs in Cambridge dictionary (which is the one I always use) I get this kind of information:

[image]

The [T] denotes that "to like" is a "transitive verb". In contrast, the Korean dictionary I use doesn't show such info.

In contrast, the Korean-English one I use doesn't really distinguish between transitive and intransitive (or at least I cannot see it):

[image]

Can you suggest a dictionary that may give more complete information (digital)?

Comment: Good point. I wonder why there's none of such..

Comment: Maybe the monolingual dictionary, but I don't know a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Korean-English dictionary in the NIKL website does not provide such information.

Instead, you can see it in the Korean-Korean dictionary.
Please search '좋아하다' in [here](https://stdict.korean.go.kr/search/searchView.do)

[image: example-like]

You may see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHalo.png) [...을].
If the information includes '...을' in the 좋아하다 example, this means that the verb is transitive.

Reference: https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=234611&pageIndex=1

Comment: Hi, do you know how to find the same info on Naver dictionary by any chance?